# Can access one shared folder, but not another

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

I am running two Windows 7 machines in the same subnet `192.168.10.0` and workgroup `WORKGROUP`. On the machine #1 I shared two physical drive letters: drive D: as DD and E: as DE. Using advanced sharing screen, I can verify that all sharing options and user accounts are exactly the same for both shares.

On the machine #2 I can browse to the machine #1: `\\192.168.10.2` and see both shares. But I can only browse one of them - DE. When I try to browse DD I get the error:

```
Windows cannot access \\M1\dd
You do not have permission to access \\M1\dd. Contact your network administrator to request access
```

The user logged into the machine #2 is one added with Full Control to the DD share. Tried other users, who have various degrees of rights, to no avail.

The same shares can be accessed from other machines on the same LAN, including Windows, Linux, Solaris and FreeBSD boxes, using the same user account as this particular machine #1, or other accounts.

What troubleshooting steps should I take in order to provide the user account logged into the machine #2 with access to the DD share?

My first step was to create another share using a folder in the D: drive. I still could not access it. But I am writing this from the Linux machine which has no problems whatsoever: Mate's Caja allows me to enter the same user account and password as used from the Windows machine #2 and instantly shows the content of any share. The Windows machine #2 takes some time (around 10-15 seconds) before it throws the error.

Comment: Are the disk permissions the same? remember, sharing permissions sit atop disk permissions, so they can limit access but can't explicitly grant it. MS actually recommends using "Everyone Full Control" at the share level, and implementing all your ACLs on the file/folder permissions, because you can copy or backup disk ACLs, but the OS controls sharing so if you have to rebuild the OS or move the folder to another location, you have to recreate all your access rules.

Comment: That was my first thought, but did not explain how the same Windows account can access the same share from a different LAN box. NTFS permissions on both drives are default and therefore the same.

Comment: could it be group membership? if you add a group to another, or a user to a group, that can dramatically affect the evaluation of the ACL. from the machine with problems, can you see the share via `net view \\serverName /all` ?

Comment: This is a workgroup, there are no groups.

Answer (score 0):

For a reason unknown to me, `TrustedInstaller` somehow claimed ownership of the root directory of the shared drive I could not access.

After reverting the ownership of the entire drive to `Administrator` the share became accessible to the newly installed Windows host.